# SLAM ROS How to make a map and visualise realtime on web using rosnodejs?

Tags: web, ros, slam, rosnodejs

I want to slam and show map on web. Now i developed the website by using rosnodejs and websocket connection. I want to know how can I make a realtime map?
Any suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what you need to give us. After you make a good attempt at doing this yourself and if you still have problems, you can update your question with details of the specific problem and what you have tried to solve it, and include your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we are able to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any SLAM package, for instance gmapping, karto, or cartographer. They will produce maps published in the OccupancyGrid format. Your rosnodejs server code can subscribe to that topic and send it your web-clients via your websockets. On the client I recommend using leaflet, or, if you are using React, react-leaflet.

This is the pipeline I've used several times and it works really well!